# Adjusting Pandas plot.hist() for better representation

Tags: python, pandas

For a data frame like this

```
      Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value
0             3            3            7            7
1             1            1            1            1
2             0            0            0            0
```

I wrote this code to create a simple histogram for the first row (2 three and 2 seven values).

```
    row = df.iloc[0]
    row.astype(int).plot.hist()
```

The result is shown below. The problem is with the position of bars. The first bar starts from 3 and the second bar ends at 7. I expected to see 3 and 7 on the axis in the middle of the bars. Also, the values on the x axis are float. I expected to see 3..7 values in integer form.

[image]

How can I fix the issues?

Comment: You _could_ specify bins that are centered on the integers: `bins=np.arange(-0.5, 10.5, 1)`

Comment: The data frame is not based on numpy.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. It _is_ because pandas is built on top of numpy, but that aside, `bins` is just an argument you can pass to the `histogram` which can be an `int`, a `str` or any sequence an `np.arange` counts as a sequence

Comment: OK. I got it. It is not working. Thanks.

Comment: To me, I often struggle with `hist` as it won't quite align well. I tend to use `value_counts()` and `plot.bar()`.  For your case as a starter, `row.value_counts().reindex(range(3, 8)).plot.bar(rot='0')`.  You can adjust xticks etc with `bar`'s params.